# Understanding of the Kronecker delta

Tags: vectors, tensors, kronecker-delta

From my understanding $e_a\cdotp e_b$ = $\delta_{ab}$ (for $a,b = 1,2,3$) equals $1$ when $a=b$ and $0$ when $a \neq b $ where $e_a$ and $e_b$ are vectors with entries 1 in the $a$'th and $b$'th row, which makes sense.

However I don't understand how $\delta_{aa} = 3$ since $a=a$ so is it not $1$? I see that in the explanation of this it says $\delta_{aa} = \delta_{11} + \delta_{22} + \delta_{22} = 3$ but is $\delta_{aa}$ not the same as taking two vectors $e_a \cdotp e_a$ which are unit vectors with entries 1 in the $a$'th row and taking the dot product would give a string of $0 \cdot 0 +...+ 1\cdot1 + ... + 0\cdot0$ which equals 1?

Further, the identity $\delta_{ab} \delta_{bc} = \delta_{ac}$ can be written as $\delta_{ab} \delta_{bc} = \delta_{a1}\delta_{1c} + \delta_{a2}\delta_{2c} + \delta_{a3} \delta_{3c}$ why does this product become the sum of three terms? and why is b allowed to change value in each term?

There is clearly something wrong with my understanding of the Kronecker Delta.

Comment: I guess you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or some isomorphic vector space, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I am, I should have specified.

Comment: This notation of a repeated index with $\delta_{aa}$ is just a notation for summation across the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Kronecker Delta per se. It is very simple: In some of the formulas you have written down, the Einstein summation convention is used, and in others not. This convention says

"Every repeated index is implicitly summed over."

If you use this convention you have
$$ \delta_{aa} \equiv \sum_{a=1}^3 \delta_{aa} = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 $$
$$ \delta_{ab} \delta_{bc} \equiv \sum_{b=1}^3 \delta_{ab} \delta_{bc} = \delta_{ac}.$$

If you do not use this convention, then you think of $a \in \{1,2,3\}$ as some fixed index and then it makes sense to say that $\delta_{aa} = e_a \cdot e_a$, for example.

Comment: So using the summation convention and not using the convention would give two different results?

Comment: @ojd: Yes, totally. $\delta_{aa}=1$ if you do not sum, for example.